# Where I can host my whatsapp selenium automation?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, web-hosting, whatsapp

I have a whatsapp automation and I want that this python file will run for nonstop.
So,

1. Did WhatsApp automation have to be on computer with screen?
2. Can I host my program on a server or something like this for keep it always running?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this question. if you have found any solution for this, please make sure to post that. Thanks!

Comment: I found a way to run whatsapp headless on server

Comment: Can we scan QR code this way?